# Visio (.vsd) file uploaded as Folder in SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visio

We are facing a strange issue (probably for a while but just noticed it):

- You save a Visio file as xxx.**vsd** to a SP library: the file is uploaded with the "Folder" content type --> as a consequence we cannot update its properties.

[image: No property available, except Name]

- You save a Visio file as yyy.**vsdx** --> the file is uploaded as a "Generic Document" (default content type of SP) and it is possible to update the properties.

[image: Properties are available]

We don't have this problem on ALL libraries. Some of them will work OK with both vsd or vsdx files.

**Do you have any clue of what could cause that strange behavior?**

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the answer in this blog post:
http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2011/10/19/sharepoint-default-library-content-type-is-folder.aspx